# php is adding backslashes to file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have a large sql file that was generate from sql studio that creates a database and tables within it. I'm using php's `get_file_contents` and going line by line to see if the line includes `CREATE DATABASE` to parse out the database name. The problem is that php is adding backslashes before every character and i'm not sure how to stop that.

```sql
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [FOOBAR-DEV]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
GO

// and so on for another 10,000 lines
```

```php
$db = "FOOBAR-DEV";
$path = sprintf('%s/../../sql/%s/createdb.sql', __DIR__, $db);
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
$name = null;
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    $needle = 'CREATE DATABASE';
    // debug code
    if ($key <= 10) {
        $output->writeln($line);
    }
    if (strpos($line, $needle) !== false) {
        $output->writeln('found');
        $name = substr($line, strlen($needle));
        break;
    }
}
$output->writeln($name);
```

The line is never found because i'm getting this:
[image]

I've tried `stripslashes` on the `$line` but that doesn't seem to do anything. I don't believe i have magic quotes on. Anything with "magic" from `php -i` just shows Imagick settings.

How can I remove the backslashes in the `$line`?

Comment: The first thing you should try is a hexdump on the input file to see if it really contains what you think it does,

Comment: I would wager that the file was originally as UTF16.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix the problem within php itself but i as able to convert the file encoding to utf-8 within PhpStorm and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I wonder if [`utf8_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) (or [`decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) ) might be any help